# start output buffering in one class method and end it in another class method

Tags: php

I have been programming in php for many, many years and have used output buffering in several of my classes and class methods. Recently, while writing a template class, my mind began to roam. The following is where my mind went :

This is just an example.

```
class someClass {
    protected $contents;

    public function __construct() {
        ob_start();
        // execute some code here.
    }

    private function someMethod() {
        // execute some code here.
        $this->contents = ob_get_contents();
    }

    public function someOtherMethod() {
        ob_end_clean();
        echo $this->contents;
    }
}
```

Consider the example code above.

**Questions**

- Can output buffering be used like this?
- The use of output buffering prevents code from being written before headers are sent, but what, if any, other benefits would come from this?
- If this is possible, is it practical?

Comment: Did you try it? And why the heck would it not work?

Comment: Honestly, I haven't tried it. I tend to get distracted easily when I have been coding for a few hours, and am trying to stay focused.... I just figured that I would ask my questions here, so that I could continue with my current task. It seems like it would work and is logical, but it is practical? Testing this may have to wait until I finish my current project.

Comment: Well, that is a silly reason to ask a question here. Please asks questions only if you can't find the answer yourself.

Comment: it will work, ob_start() is a function, and there are no scope issues with a function called in a method.  It will turn on output buffering just like it would anywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging is the biggest benefit, especially when responding to ajax requests ( ie. must return valid json even on errors, when you have no control over the other endpoint ) so you cache all out put and if a shutdown is hit ( -via- register_shutdown_function() ) you format the output as json - with the appropriate error and trace data ect. that's the biggest use i have for it. You'll have issues with nested ob_start though.  Even then it's a bit debatable if that is really useful or not.  It can also be good to dump the output to text files, for error reporting, but that is beside using it in a method, and is more dependent on your projects needs.

I do very sensitive work that needs to obscure 99% of error outputting and log it to text, and just show generic errors to end user;

this might save you some headaches

```
/**
     * dump all levels of ob_start into message
     * @return string
     */
    public static function obGetCleanNested(){
        $message = '';
        for($i=0; $i < ob_get_level(); $i++){
            $message .= ob_get_clean();
        }
        return $message;    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class buffer {

        public $output;

        public function __construct($content) { 
            ob_start();
            $this->output = $content;
        }

        public function endBuffer() { 
            $buffer = ob_get_clean();
            $this->output = $buffer;
            echo $this->output . "<br>";
        }

        public function showBufferStatus() {
            if ($this->output == null) {
                echo "nothing inside.";
            } else {
                echo $this->output;
            }
        }
    }

    $buffer = new buffer("Test"); // starts buffer
    $buffer->showBufferStatus(); // checks content inside buffer
    $buffer->endBuffer(); // ends it
    echo "still there: ", $buffer->showBufferStatus(); // checks again
```

Basically, with the function `ob_get_clean()` you actually save one move nowadays, hence no extra method. Since it executes both `ob_get_contents()` and `ob_end_clean()` at once.

Answer (score 0):

**"Can output buffering be used like this?"**

Yes, it can

**"The use of output buffering prevents code from being written before headers are sent, but what, if any, other benefits would come from this?"**

You can simple do any operation on output (compress it/change some parts)

****"If this is possible, is it practical?"****

It depends on needs. If code is written in proper way, probably you don't have to use output buffering in my opinion in most cases. However sometimes especially if you want to modify your output it's very convenient to use output bufferring

Answer (score 0):

> Can output buffering be used like this?

Yes.

> The use of output buffering prevents code from being written before headers are sent, but > what, if any, other benefits would come from this?

That's pretty much the only benefit.

> If this is possible, is it practical?

That's a matter of opinion. My opinion is no, someone else might say yes, and even someone else might say it has no "practical" effect, since php doesn't really care where, why, or how many times you call `ob_start()` or `ob_end_clean()`.

Comment: The last part of your answer is not true. PHP does care about how many times `ob_start` is called.

Comment: ^ i stand corrected. `Output buffers are stackable, that is, you may call ob_start() while another ob_start() is active. Just make sure that you call ob_end_flush() the appropriate number of times. If multiple output callback functions are active, output is being filtered sequentially through each of them in nesting order.`

Comment: see my post ob_get_level() is very useful here unless you just flush() all

Answer (score 0):

**answers**:

- Off course you can use it this way. Why would it not work?!
- other benefits are you can suppress certain output that you don't want outputted at all. In your example, all output generated between `$this->contents = ob_get_contents();` inside `someMethod()` and `ob_end_clean();` inside `someOtherMethod()` will never be outputted.
- it could be practical if you purposely don't want to output certain code. And off course as you said, to delay outputting until are headers are sent. But do be careful with how many times you call `ob_start()` as each time it will go one level deeper.